# fatal: unable to access 'https://git.tauceti.tech/rutek/exponea-php-sdk/'

Tags: php, composer-php

in my docker

```
RUN composer install --no-scripts --no-autoloader
```

composer started to fail since one hour ago

```
- Syncing tauceti/exponea-php-sdk (v0.0.7) into cache
#47 101.5
#47 101.5 In Git.php line 471:
#47 101.5
#47 101.5   Failed to execute git clone --mirror -- 'https://git.tauceti.tech/rutek/exp
#47 101.5   onea-php-sdk' '/root/.composer/cache/vcs/https---git.tauceti.tech-rutek-exp
#47 101.5   onea-php-sdk/'
#47 101.5
#47 101.5   Cloning into bare repository '/root/.composer/cache/vcs/https---git.tauceti
#47 101.5   .tech-rutek-exponea-php-sdk'...
#47 101.5   fatal: unable to access 'https://git.tauceti.tech/rutek/exponea-php-sdk/':
#47 101.5   Failed to connect to git.tauceti.tech port 443: Connection refused
```

https://git.tauceti.tech/rutek/exponea-php-sdk is indeed not available

we tried replacing it with a different fork in composer.json

```
"tauceti/exponea-php-sdk": "^0.0.7",
```

broken  new

```
"s-anton/exponea-php-sdk": "dev-master"
```

and added this repository in composer.json

```
"repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://github.com/s-anton/exponea-php-sdk"
    }
  ],
```

i also need to delete my package-lock.json. but then i got this

```
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
#46 18.05 Updating dependencies
#46 19.05 Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
#46 19.05
#46 19.05   Problem 1
#46 19.05     - Root composer.json requires s-anton/exponea-php-sdk, it could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
...
#46 19.05 Potential causes:
#46 19.05  - A typo in the package name
#46 19.05  - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
#46 19.05    see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
#46 19.05  - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it
```

‍♂️

Comment: Looking at their composer.json, the actual name of the project is `tauceti/exponea-php-sdk `

Answer (score -1):

we found a temporary solution that helps for this currently unavailable composer package

leave package in **composer.json** like this and add repo

```
"require": {
  ...
  "tauceti/exponea-php-sdk": "^0.0.7"
},
"repositories": [
  {
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "https://github.com/coldfs/exponea-php-sdk"
  }
],
```

and now the trick, do some changes in composer.lock, find entry with name **tauceti/exponea-php-sdk**

- overwrite repo in "source"
- add "dist", "autoload-dev" and "support"
- remove "notification-url"

see **composer.lock** example (extract)

```
{
    "name": "tauceti/exponea-php-sdk",
    "version": "v0.0.7",
    "source": {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "https://github.com/coldfs/exponea-php-sdk.git",
      "reference": "0252a3b022c497f2f534a2ff0f8c0f1fed68fccf"
    },
    "dist": {
      "type": "zip",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/coldfs/exponea-php-sdk/zipball/0252a3b022c497f2f534a2ff0f8c0f1fed68fccf",
      "reference": "0252a3b022c497f2f534a2ff0f8c0f1fed68fccf",
      "shasum": ""
    },
    ...
    "autoload-dev": {
      "psr-4": {
        "Tauceti\\ExponeaApiTest\\": "tests/"
      }
    },
    "support": {
      "source": "https://github.com/coldfs/exponea-php-sdk/tree/v0.0.7",
      "issues": "https://github.com/coldfs/exponea-php-sdk/issues"
    },
    ...
}
```